# Python regex replace substring and value

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to replace substring(s) {with a certain format} from a string.  And if no substring was found, append some string to the original string.

That might have been a bit confusing, so let me try to give an example.  I want to replace `AGE/age {digits}` with `AGE XXX`.  And if none is found, append  `NO AGE FOUND`.

For example, say we have a string

`He is in old age.  At AGE 51, something something.  At age 12 he bla bla.`

This should be replaced with

`He is in old age.  At AGE XXX, something something.  At AGE XXX he bla bla.`

Another example:

`He is in old age.  Something something bla bla.`

Will be replaced with:

`He is in old age.  Something something bla bla. NO AGE FOUND`

This may not make sense at all, just trying to create an example similar to the situation I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn):

```py
import re

def redact(text):
    redacted, n_found = re.subn(r"(age|AGE)\s+\d+", "age XXX", text)
    return redacted if n_found else redacted + " NO AGE FOUND"

print(redact("He is in old age.  At AGE 51, something something.  At age 12 he bla bla."))
# He is in old age.  At age XXX, something something.  At age XXX he bla bla.

print(redact("He is in old age.  Something something bla bla."))
# He is in old age.  Something something bla bla. NO AGE FOUND
```

Specifically, `re.subn` returns a tuple containing the new string and the number of substitutions made.